# Why "ConvertIBLE" and not "ConvertABLE"

Tags: orthography, suffixes, able-eable

Why do almost all words that are "able" written like:

- Comparable
- Disposable
- Doable
- Writable

Except for the word "Convertible"?

Can someone explain this to me or are there no rules tied to this?
(I was just curious).

Comment: There is a "general" rule, but I think it requires that you know whether the term is from Latin or Greek, or something along those lines, so it's easier to just look up the word (or let spell checker prompt you).

Comment: Ok, never heard of such a rule. But it would be useless to me nonetheless cause i wouldn't be "able" to identify a term being Latin or Greek ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stems from the Latin term "convertibilis", which means changeable. The term "convertible" is Old French, dating back to the 13th-14th century. I'd imagine they kept the i because it was more familiar with the original term.